# Hook into OpenSeadragon with custom user interface device

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

I'm trying to implement an interface between 1) a custom-built UI device that generates various events (scroll, click, etc) and 2) the OpenSeadragon viewer, so that the external device can be used to navigate the image. The device sends events that can be detected in a browser (javascript, of course). The online documentation shows how to intercept mouse/keyboard events to provide custom handling, but I don't see an obvious way to trigger the behavior I want (zoom, scroll) programmatically, rather than directly through the standard UI system (mouse, keyboard).

My question is, what is the right way to hook into the OpenSeadragon viewer to trigger scroll or zoom behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `viewport.panBy` and `viewport.zoomBy` methods.
See: http://openseadragon.github.io/docs/OpenSeadragon.Viewport.html

```
var viewer = new OpenSeadragon({...});

viewer.addHandler("open", function() {
    viewer.viewport.panBy(...);
    viewer.viewport.zoomBy(1.1);
});
```

The default values are 1.1 for zoom in, and 0.9 for zoom out.
For the pan, you might want to look into this function: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/blob/master/src/viewer.js#L2398